# When to use recursive function?

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I am reading about recursive function I read that when we use recursive function it calls a stack frame so if we end up calling the recursive function 10000 times it might be an issue with available memory. I have a function below is it right to use recursion? or you think I should have avoided it?

```
function animateLeft(obj, top){
   if(top >= 300){         
       obj.style.visibility = 'visible';
       return;  
   }
   else {
       var box = obj;
       box.style.marginLeft = top + "px";
       box.style.marginTop = top + "px";
       setTimeout(function(){
           animateLeft(obj, top + 1);
       }, 25) 
   }
}
function animateMe() {
    animateLeft(document.getElementById('inner-rectange'), 0);
}
```

Comment: I had a problem, and I used recursion to solve them.

Comment: It might be useful to point out that this problem can be solved in pure CSS as well

Comment: @simone I am trying to create an animation so I have to add delay not sure how it can be done with css

Comment: @Jay, CSS supports animations and transitions

Comment: I guess CSS3 does right?

Comment: I am told my code should work in IE7 too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not really using recursion since you are calling the method from `setTimeout`.

By the time the function re-executes the initial will have exited.. (*each execution does not block the next*)

Using recursion in javascript for things that manipulate the DOM is wrong, because the redrawing of the page will occur only after the whole recursion has completed.. So you will lose all intermediate steps of the animation and go from 1st step to last.

---

As mentioned in the comments to the question you could achieve this kind of animation with CSS alone..

Just set the [`transition` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) of the DOM node through CSS and then change the properties by applying a new class (*or directly through javascript*)

```
div{
    margin-left:0;
    margin-top:0;

    -moz-transition:margin 2s linear;
    -webkit-transition:margin 2s linear;
    transition:all 2s linear;
}

.move{
    margin-left:100px;
    margin-top:100px;
}
```

**See demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/rm3EP/

(*when you apply the `move` class to the `div` CSS will animate the change of the margins..*)

Comment: So does it mean the recursive functions are involved in the background while there is a delay with settimeout?

Comment: Well timeout by definition will call the callback ***after*** the time you specify has passed (*and without blocking other code from executing*)

Comment: ok What happens if I remove the setTimeout function? it will be recursive than right?

Comment: @Jay, yes then it will be recursive but then your animation will not show because while the script is running the DOM will not be updated..

Comment: I know the recursive func uses stack frames. Is it ok to use recursion for this kind of functionality or is it better to just have a loop that runs 300 times?

Comment: Thank you for the jsfiddle link but I also want the code to work in IE7 since its using some css3 properties its wont work in IE7

Comment: It is better to run a loop. Recursion is better utilized when the you need the result of the function to use it on the current run. (*loop will also not update the DOM*)

Comment: Can you tell me about the Big O notation and the memory requirements of the code?

Answer (score 5):

The use of `setTimeout` means that your code is not recursively calling the animation function directly. This will cause the function to be repeatedly invoked, but will not cause the creation of deep stack.

For an animation this is quite a reasonable approach (there are better approaches, such as `requestAnimationFrame`, but it is reasonable!)

Comment: Its a animation I am trying to create so settimeout will only add the delay.

Comment: I don't think that it is ABA recursive either as the stack will never have the same A function in it more than once. Using `setTimeout` this way just means that the function will be called over and over again, but never from itself (or some function it calls - that would generate an ABA recursion)

Comment: I have updated the answer, I see your point. It is still recursive but  will not cause the stack to 'grow' in the same way as if it were invoked directly.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use recursion to do this.  I'm not even sure if this wouldn't be done better by jQuery or something else.

I think recursion first when I'm dealing with a recursive data structure like a tree, but not for a case like this.

Comment: Or a multidimensional array of objects or something

Answer (score 0):

Your example is more of a delayed resursive function.  Because of the setTimeout there should be no problem with memory.  That current animateLeft will finish and later on the next will go.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but I have been really looking to Recursive functions as of late.
My best answer is that use recursive functions only when you do not know how many times you need to run a piece of code or when you have certain types of data structures such as trees or 
stacks